# App for remote control

Tags: android, security, parental-control, remote-control

I am looking for an app for remote control of a device. Something looks like Google Family Link, which also allows remote direct control of the target device. It is not for my children (aka parental control), but for my elderly parents who are not so tech smart (aka to avoid and preventing any threatening from the net).

The controller device will be a Samsung Galaxy A71, the target device will be a Samsung Galaxy A02s. Either are equipped with Android 11. So a specific Samsung app would be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [Airdroid](https://airdroid.com).  It had a nice interface for viewing texts, ringing/locating a lost phone, and even (if you were on LAN or paid for premium) turn on the camera.

Comment: I know AirDroid, but I am looking for something denying installing apps without my agreement, nor accessing any web page (with any browser) without my agreement. Everything would be notified to me when I am not directly connected with a remote session. In a similar fashion of how Google Family Link currently works.